# How to set razor engine to use self-defined layout page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there anyone who knows how to create another layout page for my survey without using the default( _layout.cshtml).

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just set this inside your survey views:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Path/To/Your/Layout.cshtml";
}
```

With `~/Path/To/Your/Layout.cshtml` being your custom layout view.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@{
    "~/Shared/AnotherLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: This won't use any layout page at all.